SF Deploy Issue: You can’t change this field because A has a master-detail relationship with B
I am trying to deploy a quickAction file in Salesforce environment through VScode. The quickAction file it is mainly a popup form that opens when I click a button in B page layout. There are fields from both B object and A object. What I did was to add some more fields in the form from the A object and tried to deploy the file. But I am getting this error. What should I do to fix it?

You need to include the master-detail field itself in the deployment, even if you're not making any changes to it.
This blog post from Gearset (a devops tool) explains:

There is a known bug in the Salesforce metadata API relating to
master-detail fields.
When making changes (this does not apply to adding new metadata, just
changes) to objects with master-detail fields, all the master-detail
fields must always be included in the deployment, even if they haven't
changed. This is despite the API documentation stating that only
modified fields need to be included.

